# Как поставить подпись в pdf через браузер? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, pdf

Всем привет. Друзья, хочу сделать для практики подпись pdf файла через браузер и отправить его на сервер. С отправкой проблем не возникнет, а вот с подписью pdf идей нету. Нужно чтобы клиент смог нарисовать свою подпись в pdf и сохранить его. Как можно это реализовать в javascript, есть ли какие-то библиотеки, может кто-то решал похожую задачу? Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: если имеется в виду ЭП, то без дополнительного софта на стороне клиента не обойтись (криптопровайдер+плагин для браузера). [подробнее](https://cryptopro.ru/products/cades/plugin)

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, хотите ЭП, или факсимиле в каком-то месте pdf

Comment: если без ЭП а чисто калякать мышкой или планшетом то можно вывести на сайт cavas после подписи вставить как картинку в нужное место в pdf и сохранить на сервер, например с помощью [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib#modify-document) можно отредактировать существующий. Но юридической силы такие каляки не имеют